# Determining if polygon contains point to populate point's field with polygon's name using arcpy.da?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, point

Am trying to check if the points in a point shapefile are contained within a polygon shapefile and if so, to populate a field in the point shapefile with the name of the polygon and to populate the field with 'no' if otherwise. Am guessing I have to use the contains method and I have searched but can't find examples of it used with the new data access module. I have put random values in the file paths for confidentiality. This is the code that I have but it returns an error of return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.Contains(*gp_fixargs([second_geometry])))

here's the code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace=r"K:\Shared\test"
fc="kkk.shp"
fc1="mmm.shp"
cursor=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,["SHAPE@","Reserv"])
for row in cursor:
    cursor1=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1,["SHAPE@","NAME"])
    for rowb in cursor1:
        if rowb[0].contains(row[0]):
            row[1]=rowb[1]
        else:
            row[1]="No"
del row
del row1
del cursor
del cursor1
```

Please help me figure out what's going on.

Comment: It would be *way* more efficient to do a spatial search with the polygons than to test each polygon with each point.

Answer (score 2):

You're re-establishing the cursor on fc1 on each iteration of the cursor on fc.  Why not do a spatial join, points to polys, then if you want to populate the points fc, run a secondary operation on the output with a cursor.

Comment: I upvoted because I think your Answer has the essence of a more sensible approach.  However, I would have liked to see considerable more detail.  Perhaps you can use the edit button to flesh it out sometime.

Comment: @Wayne,I know I could use a spatial join. I just didn't want to deal with the extra fields that are added when you do a spatial join. I just feel that the logic of my code makes sense(unless am missing something) and that it should be able to work and essentially give me the same results as a spatial join but without the extra fields. You said am restablishing the cursor? is that what's causing the code not to work? thanks.

Comment: I've seen something similar to what am trying to do done here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52936/arcpy-points-in-polygon-check  except I need to do it with arcpy.da